# Is any preview URL available for any GMB location's Qusetion and Answer Section...?

Tags: google-my-business-api

Current i am working on GMB API for Q&A and i want to provide a preview link of my location form which question and answers belongs to.

Like for view all reviews:
I am using https://search.google.com/local/reviews?placeid=

I am looking something same like this for Q&a.
Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to the 'Ask a Question' dialog? https://search.google.com/local/reviews?placeid= pops open the 'Write Review' box; if you want to do the same for ask a question you'll have to append a parameter to the search URL like this:

Suppose I am looking for a business on Google; I'll type 'Munchinette' which is a local restaurant here.

The result URL is:
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&gl=us&ei=FdM3XLrAIee9ggebsLzIDA&q=Munchinette&oq=Munchinette&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l2j0i10j0j0i10j0l2j0i10l2.139945.139945..140272...0.0..0.91.91.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.oTpTO0fJGxs

Now I'm going to add '#lpqa=a,,d,1' at the end of it, so my new URL is: 
https://www.google.com/search?hl=en-US&gl=us&ei=FdM3XLrAIee9ggebsLzIDA&q=Munchinette&oq=Munchinette&gs_l=psy-ab.3..35i39l2j0i10j0j0i10j0l2j0i10l2.139945.139945..140272...0.0..0.91.91.1......0....2j1..gws-wiz.oTpTO0fJGxs#lpqa=a,,d,1

The new URL will open up the 'Ask a Question' dialog because the '#lpqa=a,,d,1' parameter triggers the Google JS script to load that modal;

Now if you want the dialog to display existing Q&A, the parameter to add to the URL would be: #lpqa=d,2

Hope this helps; you can learn more about GMB tricks at https://www.reviewsmaker.com